# Name for the `::=` symbol in BNF?

Tags: parsing, bnf

Backus-Naur Form uses `::=` between the left and right sides of the production rules of a grammar.  Wikipedia tells me that notation evolved from `:≡`.  Do either of those symbols have a name?

Comment: The '::=' means that the symbol on the left must be replaced with the expression on the right. Quote from wiki ;) if it's any help. So yeah, i'd also go with "assign"

Comment: The Unicode symbol 2A74 is called "DOUBLE COLON EQUALS".

Comment: @rici:  If Unicode uses the generic name "DOUBLE COLON EQUALS", then I suspect there isn't anything more specific.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @rici's tip that Unicode simply calls it `DOUBLE COLON EQUALS`, it doesn't seem there's another official name.